# Handlebars not rendering object props and arrays in x:mailgun variables passed to custom templates through AWS lambda

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js, mailgun

I am passing the following payload through my AWS lambda:

```js
{ 
  from: 'Someone <example@email.here>',
  cc: 'Chris <example@email.here>',
  to: 'example@email.here',
  template: 'payment-request',
  'v:name': 'Client name',
  'v:lawyerName': 'Chris',
  'v:hoursBooked': '{"name":"1 hours","price":"£200","url":"https://www.example.com/booking","value":1,"selected":true,"type":"hour"}',
  'v:workTypes': '[ { name: "something 1" }, { name: "something 2" } ]' 
}
```

In the actual template I am using handlebars as follows:

```
{{name}} // Renders "Client name"
```

```
{{#each workTypes}}
  {{this.name}} // Doesn't render anything
{{/each}}
```

or even accessing an object like:

```
{{hoursBooked.name}} // Doesn't render anything
{{hoursBooked.price}} // Doesn't render anything
```

In other words, strings seems to be fine but handlebars 3.0 specifically in mailgun templates doesnt' seem to render object's property values or arrays.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The key is:

> JSON.stringify

Because few months ago i implemented this code (picture below, coming from mailgun.com inside template option menu) and doesn't worked and instead used like you did, and worked for a while and then it just stopped worked.

```
'v:workTypes': '[ { name: "something 1" }, { name: "something 2" } ]'
```

Now my code work just fine

```
var data = {
    //Specify email data
    from: from_who,
    //The email to contact
    to: mail,
    //Subject and text data  
    subject: 'Mailing List',
    template: "main_template",
    'h:X-Mailgun-Variables': ''
}

var workTypes = [ { name: "something 1" }, { name: "something 2" } ];

data['h:X-Mailgun-Variables'] = JSON.stringify({
    name: 'Client Name',
    workTypes
});
```

[image: Example code]

Answer (score 1):

Just solved my own problem:

apparently we need to use an undocumented hidden and not deductible parameter:

1. `h:X-Mailgun-Variables` in the payload we send
2. We also need to put on our wizardry hat ‍♂️ to debug their own api: if you follow their example in the official website you will never get anywhere in node.js as it will error out (`source.on`). Make sure you stringify instead as follows:

```js
'h:X-Mailgun-Variables': JSON.stringify({
  name: 'Client name',
  lawyerName: lawyerName,
  hoursBooked: hoursBooked,
  workTypes: workTypes
})
```

3. bonus: if your account is from eu, well best of luck the normal implementation won't work! But I got you covered...when passing the parameters to the `mailgun.client({})` constructor, add in the following:

```js
mailgun.client({
  username: 'api',
  key: process.env.yourkey,
  url: 'https://api.eu.mailgun.net' // This 
)}
```